# Converting RGB2HSV in OPENCV4Android

Tags: android, opencv

I have started working on OpenCv4Android recently.I was able to successfully run Image Manipulations Sample given.I wanted to covert RGB image to HSV as a test exercise.I have done OpenCv on C++(WINDOWS) and know basic functions too.

So the  cvtcolor fucntions take the following arguments: 
cvtcolor(mat src,mat dst,Imgproc.COLOR_TRANSFORMATION_TYPE,Number of Channels);
I tried different methods to check the output but I get only the cameraPreview that is the LIVE CAMERA view.Note:Other Functions like Canny Still work(shows OUTPUT).

Also I have doubt that is it neccessary to use JNI i.e NDK for this purpose or can most of the applications using OPENCV Library can me done(written) in main_activity.java and compiled??

I am starter to OpenCv4Android.Sorry If I have been over-descriptive and all suggestions are welcome. Thank You.

```
    //METHOD 1
               case ImageManipulationsActivity.VIEW_MODE_HSV:
                    rgba=inputFrame.rgba();
                    rgbaInnerWindow = rgba.submat(top, top + height, left, left + width);
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, mIntermediateMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, rgbaInnerWindow, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL);
                    rgbaInnerWindow.release();
                    break;


    //METHOD 2
           case  ImageManipulationsActivity.VIEW_MODE_HSV:
                Mat hsv= null;
            //  rgba=inputFrame.rgba();
            //  rgbaInnerWindow = rgba.submat(top, top + height, left, left + width);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaInnerWindow, mIntermediateMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(hsv, rgbaInnerWindow, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL);
                rgbaInnerWindow.release();
                break;  

   //METHOD 3
           case  ImageManipulationsActivity.VIEW_MODE_HSV:
                rgbaInnerWindow = rgba.submat(top, top + height, left, left + width);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaInnerWindow, rgbaInnerWindow, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL);
                rgbaInnerWindow.release();
                break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display HSV format image, try this code (I havn't tested it, but it should work.)

```
Mat mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
// mBgr is Mat in BGR Format
Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, mBgr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);
// mHsv is Mat in Hsv Format
Imgproc.cvtColor(mBgr, mHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV, 3);
// To display the image, we assume that mHsv is in BGR
Imgproc.cvtColor(mHsv, mRgb, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA, 4);
// Display the image
```

> Also I have doubt that is it neccessary to use JNI i.e NDK for this
>   purpose or can most of the applications using OPENCV Library can me
>   done(written) in main_activity.java and compiled??

No, you do not need to write native code for this, for most applications OpenCV Java bindings are sufficient. Even if you need to do it's pretty easy to do.

Comment: Well The code didn't work but i got the jist of it.I made the following changes and it worked thank you very much. 
<br/>
**CODE(EDITED)**  
Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaInnerWindow,mIntermediateMat,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 4);


Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat,mIntermediateMat,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV, 3);


Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat,rgbaInnerWindow,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA, 4);

                                          Srry if its not readable

Comment: It's the same code, with different variable names and since, it worked accept the answer. I had made a type before, have edited it.